# multiple sql queries using single script in isql

Tags: unix, sybase, isql

I am having few DDL queries written in multiple sql files named as 1.sql 2.sql etc 1000 f iles are there containg 2000+ create table statments

I have to use sybase  isql using unix b ox.

I want to prepare single script which can call these scripts one by one.

How to do that

Example
1.sql have create table command ends with go

Script master. sh

It contains 
isql -S Server -D database password etc -i 1.sql

Same way upto 1000.sql

Please let me know how to run

Answer (score 0):

In your master.sh try something on the following lines. The code assumes all the files exist and the files are  named from 1 to 1000 and all the files exist in the same directory as your master.sh script. You can/must add additional sanity checks to check if your sql files exist or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
    isql -S Server -D database password etc -i $i.sql
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i )); do
  isql -S Server -D database password etc -i $i.sql
done
```

To avoid having a thousand invocations of `isql`, each setting up a network connection, authenticating etc. (which will take time):

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i )); do
      cat $i.sql
done | isql -S Server -D database password etc
```

If the SQL in the various files is independent of each other (i.e. file `534.sql` may run before `55.sql`), you could even try

```
cat *.sql | isql -S Server -D database password etc
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not sure about the number of files, please move all of them to a single directory and make sure that they have the same extension (like '*.sql'). Then you can have a piece of code like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fn in `ls -l *.sql | awk '{print $9}' `
do
isql -S ServeName -D DatabaseName -U UserName -P PassWord -i $fn 
done
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`, `*.sql` will do just fine.

Comment: @Kusalananda  The parsing was used to filter the out the file names from the output of `ls -l` which normally looks like this:                               `-rw-r--r--   1 user1    group1      8279 Apr 11  2014 test.log`

Comment: The whole backtick bit may be replaced by just `*.sql`.  Calling `ls` and `awk` is not necessary.